# Use the TResult from the Task<TResult> in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I'm publishing events to an Azure Event Hub with an F# script. The equivalent C# code is as follows:

```cs
var connectionString = "<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>";
var eventHubName = "<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>";

await using (var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName))
{
    using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producer.CreateBatchAsync();
    eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(new BinaryData("First")));
    eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(new BinaryData("Second")));

    await producer.SendAsync(eventBatch);
}
```

I don't think the following is the best idiomatic F# although it works:

```ml
let producerClient = EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName)
let cancellationToken = CancellationToken()
let eventDataBatch = 
  cancellationToken
  |> producerClient.CreateBatchAsync
let edb = eventDataBatch.Result
edb.TryAdd event
producerClient.SendAsync edb
```

note: I've not included the code to create the `event` but it's a JSON string.

How can I avoid the call to `Result`? This looks like a step that could be much cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite code that uses C# async/await using the `task { .. }` computation expression in F#. Inside this, you can use `let!` in place of `await`, but also `do!` for awaiting tasks that do not return result and `use!` for awaiting `IDisposable` results.

I'm not sure what library are you using here, but something like this illustrates the syntax:

```
let connectionString = "<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>";
let eventHubName = "<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>";

let processEvent() = task {
  use producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName)
  use! eventBatch = producer.CreateBatchAsync()
  eventBatch.TryAdd(EventData(new BinaryData("First")))
  eventBatch.TryAdd(EventData(new BinaryData("Second")))
  do! producer.SendAsync(eventBatch) }
```

If you then call `processEvent()`, the result will again be `Task`. You can ignore that (and let the computation run), or wait for the result of that, if you intend to block at the top level.